# C# Read XML Element in String

Tags: c#, xml

This is my xml page. I get this from asmx webservice. I get this page with `XmlReader` nice so far. But I want to just `<urun>` strings and `<fiyat>` strings.

How I can do this ?

```
<ara xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
<urun>
<string>Rampage Smx - r51</string>
<string>Rampage X-Jammer Klavye</string>
<string>Rampage Kb-73 Klavye</string>
<string>Rampage Hectora Rh1</string>
<string>Ramtech 8gb 3000mhz Ddr4 Notebook</string>
<string>Dragos ddr4 8 gb 3200mhz ram</string>
<string>Rampage Start Rm-k6</string>
<string>Nextstar Santral Lmb</string>
<string>Rampage Tm130 Macun</string>
<string>RAMPAGE MİRACLE X3 PLUS</string>
<string>RAMPAGE MİRACLE X1</string>
<string>RAMPAGE SMX-R88</string>
<string>RAMPAGE RM-K21</string>
<string>RAMPAGE SN-RM7X</string>
<string>EVEREST RAGE-X1</string>
</urun>
<fiyat>
<string>20</string>
<string>14</string>
<string>16</string>
<string>19</string>
<string>50</string>
<string>55</string>
<string>30</string>
<string>20</string>
<string>3,5</string>
<string>31,5</string>
<string>35</string>
<string>16</string>
<string>18</string>
<string>14,5</string>
<string>11,5</string>
</fiyat>
</ara>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the example using `XmlReader`

```
var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create("XMLFile1.xml");
while (xmlReader.Read())
{
    if ((xmlReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) && (xmlReader.Name == "string"))
    {
        xmlReader.Read();
        Console.WriteLine(xmlReader.Value);
    }
}
```